# struct<const D: usize> Foo { bar : [f64, D - 1] )

Tags: generics, rust

A newbie question. I need to define a struct member as an array with size based on template parameter - but NOT the same size as template parameter:

```
struct<const D: usize> Foo {
bar : [f64, D - 1]
}
```

The above is not possible b/c of [Rust limitations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html); are there alternatives that achieve the same result? I would strongly prefer a statically-sized array for performance purposes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Until the `generic_const_exprs` feature is on stable, this will sadly require nightly. The best alternative I found so far is to refactor my code in a way that the `D - 1` becomes a simple `D`. Sadly there isn't any better alternative so far; be aware that const generics themselves are fairly new as well. It seems quite hard to get this feature right, according to the [lengthy discussions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560) and [numerous open issues](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-const-generics/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3AA-generic-exprs).